# In given Bayesian Network, are two variables 'Bayesian Network Independent'?

Tags: bayesian-networks

[image: n]

I want to test the Bayesian Network Independence between M and D.

To test Bayesian Network Independence, I should marginal out all descent nodes of M and D.

BUT, node D is descent node of M, so I'm confusing should I marginalize out D, to test BN independence btw M and D.

Similarly, how to test BN independence btw M and I for like this situation

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may find easier to understand the process of keeping the ancestors (see ancestral graph) instead of the one of removing (marginalizing out) the descendants :-)

Indeed ancestors({D,M})={M,I,D}. Ancestral graph of M->I->D is M-I-D. M and D are connected and then not independent. (The same for M->I).